# How to extract local maximum in a text file? Python

Tags: python, text, numbers

I have a text file contain a column with lots of rows. There are many zeros between numbers and the order of numbers are mostly like this: They start to increase, then they reach a maximum and then they decrease. Now I want to extract the number of this increase and decrease pattern in this data. It is also works when I extract all the local maximum values. 
The values of these local maximums are completely different with each other.
Fir example I have a file like below:

```
0
1
2
3
1
0
0
0.01
0.4
0.001
0.3
0.7
1.5
4
2
0.1
0
```

I the out put could be like this:

```
3
0.4
4
```

Comment: And what have you tried that is not working properly? Simply asking for the solution is not the way this website works. If you have some problem with code, we will help you. If you don't know how to start, the "algorithm" is quite simple, read each line and remember the previous one. When a line is smaller then previous, print previous...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to explain this best i can so you can get the way of thinking when solving this type of problems.
First thing you want to do is simply read your text file into a list of columns and convert those columns from text (`string`) into comparable numbers (`float`):

```
filename = 'numbers.txt'

with open(filename) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [float(x.strip()) for x in content]
```

After that what you must think of is the main case when one of those numbers could be local maximum: that is when it is higher than both the number before him and the number after him.
What you also have are two edge cases for the first number (does not have a number before him) and the last number (does not have a number after him).
So what you do is iterate the list with your numbers and implement those three cases with simple if statements like so:

```
local_maxes = []
for i in range(len(content)):
  if i == 0 and content[i] > content[i+1]:
    local_maxes.append(content[i])
  elif i == len(content)-1 and content[i] > content[i-1]:
    local_maxes.append(content[i])
  elif content[i] > content[i-1] and content[i] > content[i+1]:
    local_maxes.append(content[i])

print(local_maxes)
```

Full code with expected output:

```
filename = 'numbers.txt'

with open(filename) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [float(x.strip()) for x in content]

local_maxes = []
for i in range(len(content)):
  if i == 0 and content[i] > content[i+1]:
    local_maxes.append(content[i])
  elif i == len(content)-1 and content[i] > content[i-1]:
    local_maxes.append(content[i])
  elif content[i] > content[i-1] and content[i] > content[i+1]:
    local_maxes.append(content[i])

print(local_maxes)
```

Output: `[3.0, 0.4, 4.0]`